# Errors executing jobs with background job manager gem called Que

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, background-process, que

I'm writing an Rails 4.2.0 application where I need to deliver emails. I've been advised `Que` gem for managing background jobs. I've done everything as in installation and usage is listed [here](https://github.com/chanks/que).

Also I've specified in `application.rb` these lines:

```
    # For https://github.com/chanks/que
    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :que
```

My job looks like this `send_welcome_message.rb` :

```
class SendWelcomeEmail < Que::Job
  # Default settings for this job. These are optional - without them, jobs
  # will default to priority 100 and run immediately.
  @priority = 10
  @run_at = proc { 1.minute.from_now }

  def run(user_id, options)

    @user = User.find(user_id)
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now

    # Destroy the job.
    destroy
  end
end
```

After running the `rails s` command my console is populated with these messages:

```
{
   "lib":"que",
   "hostname":"...",
   "pid":13938,
   "thread":69925811873800,
   "event":"job_unavailable"
}
```

And when I enqueue my job like this in controller

`SendWelcomeEmail.enqueue 20, priority: 100`

and refresh the page, I get the following errors all the time ( despite I can send messages is sync manner without using que ):

```
    {
   "lib":"que",
   "hostname":"...",
   "pid":13938,
   "thread":69925811873800,
   "event":"job_errored",
   "error":{
      "class":"ArgumentError",
      "message":"wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)"
   },
   "job":{
      "queue":"",
      "priority":100,
      "run_at":"2015-06-22T01:59:45.187+03:00",
      "job_id":11,
      "job_class":"SendWelcomeEmail",
      "args":[
         20
      ],
      "error_count":2
   }
}
```

And when I open `rails console` in the second terminal and enter there `Que.worker_states` ([it's written here and should return information about every worker in the system](https://github.com/chanks/que/blob/master/docs/inspecting_the_queue.md#worker-states)) I get `[]`.

**I think that I have no workers spawned. Am I right? And how to fix it?**

**UPDATE**

Found error in que log:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
/home/username/train/project/app/jobs/send_welcome_email.rb:8:in `run'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/job.rb:15:in `_run'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/job.rb:99:in `block in work'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/adapters/active_record.rb:5:in `block in checkout'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/adapters/active_record.rb:34:in `checkout_activerecord_adapter'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/adapters/active_record.rb:5:in `checkout'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/job.rb:82:in `work'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/worker.rb:78:in `block in work_loop'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/worker.rb:73:in `loop'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/worker.rb:73:in `work_loop'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/que-0.10.0/lib/que/worker.rb:17:in `block in initialize'
```

Line 8 is:

```
def run(user_id, options)
```

**SOLUTION**

Now its' working. I've deleted the adapter configuration from `application.rb` and in place of

`SendWelcomeEmail.enqueue 20, priority: 100`

wrote

```
@user = User.find(20)
SendWelcomeEmail.enqueue  @user.id, :priority => 100
```

Now it's works. Funny thing in the second variant the same values are passed to the function. Still error message said that `run` obtained only 1 argument - `20`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the `que` gem, it looks like the `enqueue` method treats `priority` keyword as a special case: https://github.com/chanks/que/blob/master/lib/que/job.rb#L31

So, your `run` method is only passed the first argument. The `priority` keyword gets swallowed by `que`.

Changing your `run` method to

```
  def run(user_id)
```

should fix your issue.

Comment: I'll try it at home and write back here. thank you for investigation.